# Flex column collapsing with textarea

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I am having an issue with some flexbox styling where all of the content of a flex-column are collapsing in on each other in IE. Any help on how to get this working in IE would be greatly appreciated.

I cannot change the `flex: 1 1 0%` to `flex: 1 1 auto` as most of the styling on the site makes use of the flex-basis: 0 to calculate sizing.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container > * {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
}

.flex-container > * > * {
  display: block;
}

.flex-vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container flex-vertical">
  <label for="input">
    Input
    <input type="test" name="input" />
  </label>
  
  <label for="textarea">
    Textarea
    <textarea></textarea>
  </label>
</div>
```

[image: Correctly working in Chrome]
[image: Not working in IE]

Comment: have you tried running your CSS through autoprefixer? Depending on the version of IE you are trying to get it to work in flexbox will require `-ms-` prefixed properties, and in certain cases (IE10) different properties from the standard spec altogether https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: @WillD I have and I still get the issue.

Comment: In IE11 I got it to work by removing `flex: 1 1 0%;` from `.flex-container > *` ... I don't know why this works though.